# node pg callback event

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Hey basicly im writing a web appliaction ,i didint like to handle evrything in app.js so i did make one script called event.js what is handle the page functions and i just do export them ,my problem is its working great till i didint need to list something from the database,i know its not so elegant ,but i did tryed whit events and whit callbacks to ...here is my code whitout call or anything ,in this case first time its cant load nothing,for second render he have the values..

```
//app.js
app.get('/page',events.page);   

//event.js
exports.page = function(req,res,next) {
  if (name == 'Accounting'){
    if (req.session.ulevel == 0) {
      name='Index';
      mg='notauthed';
      show='nothing';
    } else {     
      show='accinfo';  
      name == 'Accounting';  
      console.log('asdasdasdinfoooo');
      pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client) {
        client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client));
        client.query('SELECT * FROM newtest5 where id=$1',['uid']
        , function(err,results){ 
          dlogin=results.rows[0].username;
          did=results.rows[0].id;
          dpwd=results.rows[0].password;
          demail=results.rows[0].email;     
          dregdate=results.rows[0].regdate;
          drule=results.rows[0].rights;
          dmoney=results.rows[0].balance;
          // move render here
        });
      });

      res.render('index', { 
        title: name,
        dplay:show,
        dbname:dlogin,
        dbid:did,
        dbpwd:dpwd,
        dbrule:drule,
        dbregd:dregdate,
        dbemail:demail,
        username:req.session.user,
        uid:req.session.uid,
        user:req.session.user,
        right:req.session.ulevel,
        content:contents[name],
        msg:msgs[mg]
      }), console.log('data:'+dlogin);
    }
  } 
}
```

my object is when the name is accounting in this code ,i like to render one page ,whit the loaded information ,not before as now its working,basicly i just routing in app js ,and evry function ,and the renders also are totaly exported from event js ,its basicly working very well,just problem is ..render is runing before the database read is finished..somehow i need to make render wait the data read end,then execute the render.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: I know its not so safe,but this is the most of smallest problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation made it impossible to see what was going on. I reindented it. When you call `pg.connect(str, callback)`, you pass it a callback where you define `dlogin` etc. But after you call `pg.connect` you IMMEDIATELY call `res.render()`! The javascript engine waits for no man. The proper way is to put `res.render()` inside your innermost callback. This will make sure the response isn't sent until you have actually defined `dlogin` etc.

You may also use `res.locals` if you want to set variables for jade to use (or presumably other template engines)

```
//app.js
app.get('/page',events.page);   

//event.js
exports.page = function(req,res,next) {
  if (name == 'Accounting'){
    if (req.session.ulevel == 0) {
      name='Index';
      mg='notauthed';
      show='nothing';
    } else {     
      show='accinfo';  
      name == 'Accounting';  
      console.log('asdasdasdinfoooo');
      pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client) {
        client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client));
        client.query('SELECT * FROM newtest5 where id=$1',['uid']
        , function(err,results){ 
          res.locals.dlogin=results.rows[0].username;
          res.locals.did=results.rows[0].id;
          // etc...
          console.log('data:'+res.locals.dlogin); 
          // ... it gets set here, when the callback is finally run
          res.render('index');
        });
      });

      console.log('data:'+res.locals.dlogin);  
      // this will be undefined after defining the callback, until the callback is run
      // pg.connect() has been run, but not its callback, yet
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanx bro for re editing my post ,ur solution looking very well,just problem is its effect nothing,i mean the render didint run nowhere..just first time when i tryed its seems as working,cuse until ur answere i tryed to bypass it ,whit that to load all data in begining,the render is didint load the varibles from database ,in this way .

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access a database object that you created in app.js, from within event.js, you can pass the database into event:

```
//app.js
var db = require('someDB');
var event = require('./event.js')(db);
event.someFunction(function(err, data){ 
  console.log(data);
});

//event.js
module.exports = function(db){
  var event = {};

  event.someFunction = function(callback){
    db.fetch('someone', function(err, data){
      callback(err, data);
    });
  };

  return event;
}
```

Comment: pls chek now again,i did edited my stuf to explain it more a bit how its looks now ,anyway thx for ur help

Comment: you are referencing `pg.connect` in event.js; where are you defining `pg`? does event.js have the right `pg` object? if `pg` is created in app.js, pass it in as I demonstrate above

Comment: Oh you might also need to move the `res.render` call into your innermost callback